# Kafka Stream reprocessing old messages on rebalancing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams application which reads data from a few topics, joins the data and writes it to another topic.

This is the configuration of my Kafka cluster:

```
5 Kafka brokers
Kafka topics - 15 partitions and replication factor 3.
```

My Kafka Streams applications are running on the same machines as my Kafka broker.

A few million records are consumed/produced per hour. Whenever I take a  broker down, the application goes into rebalancing state and after rebalancing many times it starts consuming very old messages.

**Note: When the Kafka Streams application was running fine, its consumer lag was almost 0. But after rebalancing, its lag went from 0 to 10million.**

Can this be because of **offset.retention.minutes**.

This is the log and offset retention policy configuration of my Kafka broker:

```
log retention policy : 3 days
offset.retention.minutes : 1 day
```

In the below link I read that this could be the cause:

[Offset Retention Minutes reference](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/KAFKA-3806)

Any help in this would be appreciated.

Comment: When is offset committed if auto.commit.offset.enable=false?
Should I set auto.commit.enable=true? will it have any impact?

Answer (score 2):

Offset retention can have an impact. Cf this FAQ: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#why-is-my-application-re-processing-data-from-the-beginning

Also cf [How to commit manually with Kafka Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416178/how-to-commit-manually-with-kafka-stream) and [How to commit manually with Kafka Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416178/how-to-commit-manually-with-kafka-stream/43418336#43418336) about how commits work.