# Handling transactions with Kafka Streams and Spring-Cloud-Stream

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am developing an app (microservices-based) relying on Kafka and Kafka Streams. I am using Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Stream for that and I am having trouble with handling transactions for Kafka Streams operations. I know that there is no problem with handling transactions purely with Kafka consumer however when I try to add Kafka Streams processing in the middle it becomes tricky to me.

The example case is:

> 1. In one of my services order request for a product is consumed from topic A.
> 2. Inventory info is consumed from topic B
> 3. This service produces inventory updates to topic B but it is also responsible for publishing events regarding products being ready for shipping (to topic C)
> 4. When receiving order request from topic A I want to check (by processing topic B) whether inventory for particular product is sufficient and publish an event with either success or failure (regarding that order) to topic C.
> 5. At the same time I need to update inventory (subtract the quantity that is let's say reserved for shipping) so that for next order I have actual values from topic B. I want to post success to topic C and update inventory on topic B within one transaction.

Is that possible in spring cloud stream with kafka streams? And if yes, how can I manage to do that?

Comment: Spring Cloud Stream relies on the transactional capabilities provided by Apache Kafka. You might want to look up on how to do that in Kafka. This post has a handful of links you can follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48268771