# Kafka streams Deserialisation exception| Log and continue e

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am facing the same issue as
[Kafka Streams Deserialization Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470899/kafka-streams-deserialization-handler)

After using logandcontinue, still on restarting server the corrupt messages show up everytime.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this jira issue is still open and needs to be addressed to fix the problem you are describing: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6502

It only happens when you have a series of records in error though. As soon as you have a good record coming in, the offset moves along. Therefore, as a workaround, you can probably send a good record that will not cause an error maybe?

Comment: On restarting the server every time, we see the logs of the corrupt messages due to deserialisation exception. Though it processes the good messages and stream is not blocked with LogAndContinue. But the deserialisation error logs still come up each time server is started. Is there any other known way to deal with this?

Comment: Hmm - that should work then. Can you share a small reproducible sample app? Then we can triage further.