# How to decide the correct parameters for Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The core application takes 500ms on average to process a record.

I have tried the below patterns. Unfortunately, I couldn't get rid of rebalancing.

**Total events:** 3,60,000.

**Confluent platform:** 3Node cluster, each 2TB disk, SSD disk, Better NIC, VM.

**Application node details**: Has 24 cores, 96GB Memory, While running the application used memory is 20GB(may be other application also consuming), 400% CPU usage(I have 24 cores).

**Source topic detail:** 1 topic, 10 partitions.

[image: Processing details]

Here, the entities decide the processing speed of an event.

all - at max 100 entities per record(event,kafka message), average processing time for this is 500ms

20 - at max 20 entities per record(event, kafka message), average processing time is lesser

I referred many forums [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416178/how-to-commit-manually-with-kafka-stream), [KIP 62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread), Confluent docs, @Matthias J.Sax answers, [this blog](https://chrzaszcz.dev/2019/06/kafka-heartbeat-thread/).

I am having hard time to set these values to avoid rebalancing.

Hearbeat expiration logs:

```
[2021-07-27 07:11:50,775] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Preparing to rebalance group 
abc in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 594 (__consumer_offsets-13) 
(reason: removing member abc-990854d8- 
f8d7-4b77-9318-2542000258d2-StreamThread-1-consumer-badbdf8b-6705-4319-be8f-57a71d2366ef 
on heartbeat expiration) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

The moment `max.poll.records` reduced to 10, there are no heartbeat expiration. But rebalancing due to metadata change(?)

```
[2021-07-28 12:09:03,030] INFO [GroupCoordinator 3]: Preparing to rebalance group abc 
in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 10 (__consumer_offsets-13) 
(reason: Updating metadata for member 
abc-e0cb67ba-e587-44f9-844b-746cd498392a-StreamThread-1-consumer- 
e875d55d-75b5-4b0a-ad10-cc045223690d during Stable) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

The thing which confuses me a lot was heartbeat expiration - no network error, the application didn't crash. Why does this error occur and the application receives the duplicate message at this time[Time matches from the logs(application log, kafka log)]

Another two executions:

[image: Latest two executions]

Is there any reason for metadata update when none of the thread is down(assuming from the logs, there are no heartbeat expiration)? How do we control this minimum duplicates?